# How to display Twitter timeline in Ionic app?

Tags: angularjs, twitter, ionic-framework

**THE SITUATION:**

I need to display a Twitter timeline in my Ionic app. Just that. No further action is needed (login, retweet etc..)

**ATTEMPT 1 - SIMPLE EMBED** (as in a normal website)

In the view:

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/MY_TWITTER" data-widget-id="TWITTER_WIDGET_ID">Tweets by @MY_TWITTER</a>
```

The script in index.html:

```
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

Is not working. Testing the actual app in the phone, is not showing up. Testing the app in the browser it appears only after refreshing the page.

Bu if i put that same lines of code into a simple angular web app (not a Ionic app) than it works fine.
Why there is this strange behavior? Is ionic related?

**ATTEMPT 2 - NGTWITTER**

This is the code as explained in this tutorial: http://devdactic.com/twitter-rest-api-angularjs/

The controller:

```
.controller('TwitterCtrl', function($scope, $ionicPlatform, $twitterApi, $cordovaOauth) {


  var twitterKey = 'STORAGE.TWITTER.KEY';
  var clientId = 'MY_CLIENT_ID';
  var clientSecret = 'MY_CLIENT_SECRET';
  var myToken = '';

  $scope.tweet = {};

  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

    myToken = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem(twitterKey));
    if (myToken === '' || myToken === null) {
      $cordovaOauth.twitter(clientId, clientSecret).then(function (succ) {
        myToken = succ;
        window.localStorage.setItem(twitterKey, JSON.stringify(succ));
        $twitterApi.configure(clientId, clientSecret, succ);
        $scope.showHomeTimeline();
      }, function(error) {
         console.log(error);
      });
     } else {
      $twitterApi.configure(clientId, clientSecret, myToken);
      $scope.showHomeTimeline();
    }

  });


  $scope.showHomeTimeline = function() {
    $twitterApi.getUserTimeline({screen_name: 'MY_TWITTER_FEED'}).then(function(data) {
       $scope.home_timeline = data;
     });
  };

  $scope.submitTweet = function() {
   $twitterApi.postStatusUpdate($scope.tweet.message).then(function(result) {
      $scope.showHomeTimeline();
    });
  };

  $scope.doRefresh = function() {
    $scope.showHomeTimeline();
    $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
  };

  $scope.correctTimestring = function(string) {
    return new Date(Date.parse(string));
  };

});
```

The view:

```
    <div class="list">
      <div class="item item-input-inset">
        <label class="item-input-wrapper">
          <input type="text" placeholder="My tweet..." ng-model="tweet.message" ng-maxlength="140">
        </label>
        <button class="button button-small" ng-click="submitTweet()">
          Tweet
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <ion-refresher on-refresh="doRefresh()"></ion-refresher>

    <div ng-show="home_timeline.length == 0">Loading tweets...</div>

    <div ng-repeat="entry in home_timeline" class="list card">
      <div class="item item-avatar">
        <img ng-src="{{entry.user.profile_image_url}}"/>
        <h2>{{entry.user.name}}</h2>
        <p>{{correctTimestring(entry.created_at) | date:'medium'}}</p>
      </div>

      <div class="item item-body">
        <p ng-bind-html="entry.text"></p>
        <img ng-if="entry.extended_entities" ng-src="{{ entry.extended_entities.media[0].media_url }}" style="width: 100%;"/>
      </div>

    </div>
```

In this way i can properly see the twitter feed requested plus the possibility to write tweets.
Is not exactly what i want, because it requires the user to login into Twitter and allow the app to be granted access to his twitter account, while i just want to display a twitter feed and nothing more.

Besides, once the twitter section of the app is opened the app is not working anymore as excepted, some links in the menu stop to work.

**THE QUESTION:**

How can i simply display a twitter timeline inside a Ionic app?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi , In your timeline requirement the tweet's must  be updated automatically?

Comment: Hi, I posted a sample project in github in github to login via twitter have you checked that project?

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I have tried but is not working. It is using basically the same plugin i have tried, right? Thanks anyway

Comment: Thanks for the reply, It is worked for me and I am able to get the timeline tweet's from twitter,can you paste your error log's so that I will get an Idea and I will try to fix it

Comment: In the broswer i get no errors. In the emulator (Genymotion) i try to press the button and nothing happens.

Comment: OK i will update my APPID and APPSECRET value's in the updated project, check it with that value's and update if you have any error's

Comment: I have updated my code in github with APPID & APP SECRET now check it and reply if you face again any errors

Answer (score -1):

I uploaded a sample project in git hub for [Twitter Login](https://github.com/anilkumar007/Twitter_login) in Ionic framework if you have any queries please let me know 
Before cloning the project follow these step's : 
1)Create a developer project in Twitter Developer console 
2)Replace the APPID and APPSECRET in project with your values created in twitter developer console 
3)Please write the call back url in twitter developer application as http://tinyurl.com/krmpchb 
4)Have a look at README.md file in github